# Loop not iterating

Tags: python

I'm running into a dilemma with a for i in range(x) loop not iterating. The purpose of my program is to simulate foxes  and rabbits interacting with one another on an island and printing out the populations of each respective animal after each day. I know the equations are correct, the problem I am having is my loop will only run once for a large range.

My code:

```
def run_simulation():
    print()
    RABBIT_BIRTH_RATE = 0.01
    FOX_BIRTH_RATE = 0.005
    INTERACT = 0.00001
    SUCCESS = 0.01
    x = 0
    y = 1
    FOXES = eval(input("Enter the initial number of foxes: "))
    print()
    RABBITS = eval(input("Enter the initial number of rabbit: "))
    print()
    DAYS = eval(input("Enter the number of days to run the simulation: "))
    print()
    print("Day\t","Rabbits\t","Foxes\t")
    print(0,"\t",RABBITS,"\t","\t",FOXES,"\t")
    for i in range(DAYS):
        RABBITS_START = round((RABBIT_BIRTH_RATE * RABBITS) - (INTERACT * RABBITS * FOXES))
        FOXES_START = round((INTERACT * SUCCESS * RABBITS * FOXES) - (FOX_BIRTH_RATE * FOXES))
        y = y + x
        print (y,"\t",(RABBITS_START+RABBITS),"\t","\t",(FOXES_START+FOXES),"\t")
run_simulation()
```

When this is run  with an example of 500 Foxes, 10000 Rabbits, and 1200 days, my output will look like

```
Day  Rabbits     Foxes  
0    10000       500    
1    10050       498
```

With the second output line repeating the remaining 1199 times.
Any help would be greatly appreciated I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You do `y = y+x`, but you never change `x` from 0.  Also, you never use the loop variable `i`, so it's not surprising your loop has no effect.

Comment: Okay I changed the days to be correct and then changed the loop to act as for DAYS in range (DAYS):  Now the days work but the foxes and rabbits remain to only be calculated once.

Comment: Don't use `eval()`. Use `int()`.

Comment: Following up on `forivall`'s comment: `eval(input(…))` is almost always a bad idea. If they give you `2.5` or `"string"` or `__import__(os).system('rm -rf /')`, you don't want that to succeed, do you? So just do `int(input(…))`. That won't affect _this_ problem; it's a separate problem.

Comment: @abarnert `__import__(os).system('rm -rf /')`. I lol'

Answer (score 3):

You set `RABBITS` and `RABBIT_BIRTH_RATE` at the beginning.  Then, on every loop iteration, you set `RABBITS_START` to some formula involving these two numbers.  You never change the value of `RABBITS` or `RABBIT_BIRTH_RATE` or `FOXES` or anything, so every time you run through the loop, you're just calculating the same thing again with the same numbers.  You need to update the values of your variables on each iteration --- that is, set a new value for `RABBITS`, `FOXES`, etc.

Comment: But why does it only print once. It should print the same line 1200 times.

Comment: @Cruncher: It does, he just truncated the output in his post.  Below the output it says it repeats 1199 times.  (The first output line is from the print before the loop begins, which is why it's different.)

Comment: Look [here](http://tinyurl.com/ohqtt8j) to watch the code execute, starting at the entry to the first loop. It explains BrenBarn's answer better than any text explanation could.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest issue for me is what you named your "change in rabbits/foxes". `RABBITS_START` sounds like an initial count for `RABBITS`, but it's not. This is why I renamed it to `RABBITS_DELTA`, because really it's calculating the CHANGE in rabbits for each day.

I think I got it. At the very least this behaves more like a simulation now:

```
def run_simulation():
  RABBIT_BIRTH_RATE = 0.01
  FOX_BIRTH_RATE = 0.005
  INTERACT = 0.00001
  SUCCESS = 0.01
  x = 0
  y = 1

  FOXES = eval(str(input("Enter the initial number of foxes: ")))
  RABBITS = eval(str(input("Enter the initial number of rabbits: ")))

  DAYS = eval(str(input("Enter the number of days to run the simulation: ")))

  print("Day\t","Rabbits\t","Foxes\t")
  print(0,"\t",RABBITS,"\t","\t",FOXES,"\t")

  count = 0
  while count < DAYS:
    RABBITS_DELTA = round((RABBIT_BIRTH_RATE * RABBITS) \
                          - (INTERACT * RABBITS * FOXES))
    FOXES_DELTA = round((INTERACT * SUCCESS * RABBITS * FOXES) \
                        - (FOX_BIRTH_RATE * FOXES))
    y = y + x

    RABBITS += RABBITS_DELTA
    FOXES += FOXES_DELTA
    print (y,"\t",(RABBITS),"\t","\t",(FOXES),"\t")

    count += 1


run_simulation()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a wild stab at trying to interpret what you mean:

```
for i in range(1, DAYS + 1):
    rabbit_delta = ... # RABBITS_START
    fox_delta = ... # FOXES_START
    RABBITS += rabbit_delta
    FOXES += fox_delta
    print(i, "\t", RABBITS, "\t\t", FOXES, "\t")
```

**edited** based on others' answers. (Wild stab is less wild.)

See BrenBarn's answer for an explanation in prose.

Comment: Thank you and BrenBarn, I'm sorry if this seemed like a simple question I am kind of new to python, this helped.